# hover style of custom checkbox with font awesome

Tags: css, checkbox, font-awesome

I have some simple html/css with font awesome fonts to customise a checkbox. I am struggling to modify the colour (to red for now) when the checkbox is hovered.

As I am using a font awesome font to customise the checkbox, I assumed I needed to apply the css on hover of the label but its not having the desired effect.

```
 input.faChkRnd:hover + label:before {
   color: red;
 }
```

This seems to change only on click of the checkbox and not when hovering.

any help appreciated!

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rajenmanani/p1bLm3y5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't hover the input as it is `display: none`. Add your `:hover` to the label:

```
input.faChkRnd + label:hover:before {
  color: red;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p1bLm3y5/2/)

Answer (score -1):

we cannot target hover state on an element which has `display:none` property. we can have a hover on `label`.

```
//when input is not checked
input.faChkRnd + label:hover:before {
  color: red;
}

//when input is checked
input.faChkRnd:checked + label:hover:before {
  color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a0s0gkxb/3/

This library might help to customise checkboxes and radio buttons , https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox/